# how to shorten php condition?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, switch-statement

hello i have the following problem:

i have a form in that i would like to check via php for some input errors. beside that i would like to display an user information about whats being wrong.

the problem i have is, that i only like to display one message and not all at same time. therefor i need to filter all error messages from php to limit that to one.

so php is looking for this:

```
<?php if (isset($errors['for_a']):?><div id="errormessage">some text</div><?php endif; ?>
```

and the php rule is:

```
(case1) ... if ( isset($errors['for_a']) AND (!isset($errors['for_b'])) AND (!isset($errors['for_c'])) OR (!isset($errors['for_d'])) ...
OR
(case 2) ...AND (!isset($errors['for_b'])) AND (!isset($errors['for_c'])) AND (!isset($errors['for_d'])) ...
and so on for input field a...
```

so the problem is that i have 7 input fields and this would mean i have to write all possibilities. is there a way to shorten this?

thanks a lot.

UPDATE:

okay, maybe its not clear enough what i like to achieve.

i do not have problems displaying the error message. this works fine. each error message for each specific input field could be displayed correctly.

the problem is that i have different error messages for each of it. i do store that in a more dimensional array:

```
if(empty($a)){$errors['a'][]="first failure for a"}
if(something else happens($a)){$errors['a'][]="second failure for a"}
...

if(empty($b)){$errors['b'][]="first failure for b"}
if(something else happens($b)){$errors['b'][]="second failure for b"}
...
```

displaying that error messages is also not the problem.

```
<?php if (isset($errors['a'])):?>
<?php echo "<div class='erl'>"; 
echo $errors['a'][0];
echo "</div>";          
endif;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

the problem is the conditions for displaying only one error message at same time!

so here are some graphics to show what i mean:

this is the situation at the moment, all error divs will be displayed at the same time:

[image: f0]

this is what i like to achieve, that only one error message will be displayed at the same time start checking by the first input field:

[image: f2]

so that user will be forced to correct the first input field before displaying the second error layer:

[image: f5]

hope it gets clear now.

Comment: Speaking in general terms, I think you are thinking it in a wrong way. As a user, I'd be pretty upset if I have to send the form multiple times to know all the errors because you only show one mistake at a time. If you show all at once it is much more usable. But if you are making a quiz or test it may have sense doing it your way.

Comment: there are some else error divs that shows the user, that there are some problems with that. but if he likes to know whats being wrong he probably can see it before he submits the form. having to much information at same time becomes a little bit confusing. too much information at once. so thats the reason why i want it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking. Usually with forms, if you have lots of fields you can create an array of errors, and either display the errors as a bullet list at the top of the form, or inline with its corresponding form element.

```
<?php
$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // for each form field check it's valid, if it's not add a key to the errors array, i.e.
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $errors['name'] = 'Name is a required field';
    }
}

// display form
?>
```

You'll now have an `$errors` array. If it's not empty, your form had errors. You can then display these errors in one of two ways. As a bullet list at the top of your form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
<?php if (!empty($errors)): ?>
      <p>Please correct the following errors:</p>
      <ul>
<?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
        <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
      <!-- the rest of your form -->
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or inline with each form field:

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="input">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<?php if (isset($errors['name'])): ?>
    <div class="error"><?php echo $errors['name']; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</form>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, thanks but i doesnt. i updated my question to give further information.

Comment: If you have multiple errors per form field, then I'd just say the first one.

Comment: sorry, i do not understand what you are meaning. i dont need them as a bullet list in one div. i have my layer class that will be displayed beside. that all works. the question is just how to limit the displaying method to one at same time.

Comment: Check out PHP functions like `array_pop()` and `array_unshift()`. Use them to show just one error message at a time in your template.

Comment: i think even this does not help. because it will count the errors but how can i use this to limit the number displaying divs for error message?

Comment: okay, it seems like we are talking about different things. i updated my question with some pics to show what i mean. thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do you do your error treatment?

If you only set `$errors['for_a']`, etc... if there is an error in the input field `for_a`, you can just do:

```
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    foreach ($errors as $input => $errormsg) {
        echo '<div id="errormessage">' . $errormsg . '</div>'
    }
} else {
    // continue normally
}
```

Comment: hello, i have a more dimensional array. that looks like: if(empty($a)){$errors['a'][]="error for a"....if(empty($b)){$errors['b'][]=""error for b"... and so on. so each inputfield has its own specific error messages. so i dont think this would help because using count errors would be usefull when i only would have one possibilities of errors but there are 7! (mathematics expression) possibilieties!

Answer (score 0):

How about an OO solution? Something like:

`<?php echo $errors->show('for_a', 'some text'); ?>`

where $errors points to a class that will output the 'some text' only if it hasn't outputted anything before.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest solution is to use a globalvariable that holds if you displayed an error.

eg:

```
$errorShown = false;
```

And a function:

```
function showError($whatError,$errArr){
  global $errorShown;
  if ((isset($errArr[$whatError])) && (!$errorShown)){
    echo $whatError;
    $errorShown = true;
  }
}
```

and call that function instead.

```
<?php showError('for_a',$errors); ?>
```